# Suppress output string using FORFILES command

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, forfiles

I want ignore the seconds of the output `@ftime` using `forfiles`:

```
forfiles /P "%userprofile%\Desktop\folder" /M "test.rar" /C "cmd /c echo sucessufull at %@ftime:~0,2%:%@ftime:~3,2%h"
```

Tried using this way, but I think `forfiles` doesn't allow use of `%`.

Comment: Why are you using `forfiles`? The command you're using can only provide output for a single known file, `%userprofile%\Desktop\folder\test.rar`, so a standard [tag:for-loop] would be just as effective, a little more efficient, and easier to manipulate the resulting last modified `time` data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a basic example of your command directly using [forfiles](/questions/tagged/forfiles), to stay on topic:

```batch-file
@ForFiles /P "%UserProfile%\Desktop\folder" /M "test.rar" /C "Cmd /V /C Set _=@FTime&Echo successful at !_:~,5!"
```

And a more complete/robust example:

```batch-file
@"%__AppDir__%forfiles.exe" /P "%UserProfile%\Desktop\folder" /M "test.rar" /C "0x22%__AppDir__%cmd.exe0x22 /V /C If @IsDir==FALSE (Set 0x22_=@FTime0x22 & Echo successful at !_:~,5!)"
```

Answer (score 2):

The special `@`-variables of [`forfiles`](https://ss64.com/nt/forfiles.html), like `@ftime`, have nothing to do with normal environment variables, which `%`-signs are used for to expand them.

There are two options:

1. Capture the output of `forfiles` with [`for /F`](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html):

   ```cmd
    for /F "tokens=1-2 delims=:" %%I in ('
        forfiles /P "%UserProfile%\Desktop\Folder" /M "test.rar" /C "cmd /C if @isdir==FALSE echo @ftime"
    ') do (
        echo successful at %%I:%%Jh
    )
   ```
2. nest `for /F` loop inside of `forfiles`:

   ```cmd
    forfiles /P "%UserProfile%\Desktop\Folder" /M "test.rar" /C "cmd /C if @isdir==FALSE for /F 0x22tokens=1-2 delims=:0x22 %%I in (0x22@ftime0x22) do echo successful at %%I:%%Jh"
   ```

   The hex code `0x22` stands for a quotation mark `"` and is only understood by `forfiles`.